# What is the difference between node.isSameNode(node1) and node === node1 in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
var a = document.getElementById('a');
var b = document.getElementById('a');

a.isSameNode(b); // true
a === b; // true
```

What is the browser compatibility of each approach?

Answer (score 2):

isSameNode was deprecated in [DOM v4](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/).  Firefox dropped support in version 10. I believe other major browsers support it, for now.

The recommended approach is to use '==='

Comment: Are you sure it's deprecated? I don't see anything about that on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isSameNode).

Comment: I stand corrected, FF did not drop support.  However it was removed in DOM v4: https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-core

Comment: Firefox did drop support in v10 but readded it in v48 according to the their [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isSameNode#Browser_compatibility). Is it stated somewhere in the standard that `===` is guaranteed to work (e.g., `document.querySelector('element') === document.querySelector('element')`)?

Comment: “the recommended approach” … by whom? If you are personally recommending it, please state so, otherwise please provide a citation. also, please correct the Firefox dropping claim (not everyone reads the comments).